# node.js setInterval does not trigger a this. object

Tags: node.js, time, setinterval

When the page loads the console log part of the function works showing me the current seconds + 3, but it does not repeat and the (innerText =....) does not work at all. I only added the console log part to the code to try to troubleshoot, the inner text change is the important part.

```
class Main {
  constructor() {
    // Initiate variables
    this.TimerTexts = [];
    this.infoTexts = [];
    this.training = -1; // -1 when no class is being trained
    this.videoPlaying = false;

    this.currentTime2 = new Date(Date.now());
    this.currentTime = new Date(Date.now());
    this.remTime = this.currentTime.getSeconds() + 3;
    this.looper = window.setInterval(this.intervalfunc(), 1000);
  }

  // ...

  intervalfunc() {
    this.TimerTexts.innerText = `Time: ${this.remTime} `;
    console.log(this.remTime);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're *calling* `intervalfunc`, not passing in as the function for `setInterval`.

In addition, you'll need to bind the function to your instance.

```
this.looper = window.setInterval(this.intervalfunc.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: I added the .bind and (this), so now the console does output the seconds +3 but the inner text still remains unchanged. Also I noticed that it only outputs the same number 39, 39, 39 instead of 39, 40 , 41, 42

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow function, inside arrow function you can call intervalfunc.

```js
class Main {
  constructor() {
    // Initiate variables
    this.TimerTexts = [];
    this.infoTexts = [];
    this.training = -1; // -1 when no class is being trained
    this.videoPlaying = false;

    this.currentTime2 = new Date(Date.now());
    this.currentTime = new Date(Date.now());
    this.remTime = this.currentTime.getSeconds() + 3;
    this.looper = window.setInterval(()=>this.intervalfunc(), 1000);
  }

  intervalfunc() {
    this.TimerTexts.innerText = `Time: ${this.remTime} `;
    console.log(this.remTime);
    this.remTime += 3;
  }
}

new Main()
```

**OR you can do**

```js
class Main {
  constructor() {
    // Initiate variables
    this.TimerTexts = [];
    this.infoTexts = [];
    this.training = -1; // -1 when no class is being trained
    this.videoPlaying = false;

    this.currentTime2 = new Date(Date.now());
    this.currentTime = new Date(Date.now());
    this.remTime = this.currentTime.getSeconds() + 3;
    var self = this;
    this.looper = window.setInterval(this.intervalfunc.bind(self), 1000);
  }

  intervalfunc() {
    this.TimerTexts.innerText = `Time: ${this.remTime} `;
    console.log(this.remTime);
    this.remTime += 3;
  }
}

new Main()
```

Comment: thank you for the help but just like the answer by AKX the inner text remains unchanged and the output does not increase.

Comment: @HoneyCentaur it'll not change, because it's not updating function.

Comment: Im very new to node.js can you elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: if you want to update any value after some interval you need to write inside setInterval. the constructor will execute only once and set the value to `this.remtime`. 
I have updated my answer refer that.

Comment: should I post the code for the element which the inner text should change? because it still stays the same